# Is there a simple/complicated way to create requestData() method using Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

As the title says, I need a way(no matter if its complicated or not) to create a getData() method that would send request packet to the server > receive the message I already have the system setup but I have a problem with it that I only get the result in `PluginMessageReceiveEvent` Here's my code with explanations:

```
public String requestData(String path) {
    SocketUtils.sendData("REQUEST|" + p.getPlayer().getUniqueId() + "|" + path, "playerconfig", "BUNGEE");
    return /*Need to get data from the plugin message to here*/;
}

@EventHandler
public void onPluginMessageReceive(PluginMessageReceiveEvent e) {
    if (e.getChannel().equalsIgnoreCase("playerconfig")) {
        String[] args = e.getMessage().split("\\|");
        String uuid = args[0];
        String path = args[1];//Maybe a HashMap<Path, Data> but that would make the requestData() result return null because you don't get the data instantly.
        String data = args[2].replace("_", " ");
        if (uuid.equals(p.getPlayer().getUniqueId() + "")) {
            return data; //I need to get this result on request data method.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would a `getData()` method *send* anything? There's a way to create methods that do most things, and often easy ways, but without a proper specification this question is just a time-waster.

Comment: @EJP this question was already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to `wait` on a lock in the `requestData` and notify that lock in `onPluginMessageReceive`. Something like this:

```
 synchronized(this) {
    wait();
 }
```

And in your receive method:

```
 synchronized(this) {
    notifyAll();
 }
```

Make the data a member field of the class.

Look out for exception handling and syntax errors.

Comment: What does the `SocketUtils.sendData` do? Is it a synchronous call that returns only after a reply is received? In that case, just making data member variable should work. No need to wait/notify.

Comment: My sendData() method. No it just sends a socket to masterserver it handles the socket and does stuff with it: http://pastebin.com/xcLAPF9S

Comment: My mistake I forgot to call `SocketUtils.setup()`

Comment: How do I make something that if I don't get a reply in amount of seconds, it calls a method or something?

Comment: `wait` has a variant that can take time in milli as a parameter. Remember that it doesn't throw an exception. So after the wait call you still need to check whether there is a response or not. Best is to set `data` to `null` before sendData and check that it is not null after the `wait` call.